# All converted apps including samples fail to run with a 'The parameter is incorrect'

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, desktop-app-converter

I'm trying to convert a WPF oneclick installed application and so everything should be pretty straight forward. However, whenever I run the debug project, I get

'The parameter is incorrect'

in a message box popup and I can never run the app.

This happens for my app while trying to debug, all the samples from github, and even the DAC application from the Windows Store. The error pops up even once the app is installed and showing in my application list.

I'm on the latest build of the Creators Update.

There are various errors in the event viewers, but they seem to be a common occurence for WinRT apps.

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Hey Matt; can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Hi John, nothing in the calls stack window of visual studio when i run the debugging samples.

Comment: And the Desktop App Converter itself pops up the same error. Is there somewhere in the folder C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe where i can find a stack trace of some kind?

Comment: The dll you mentioned above sounds like a Microsoft application?  If so it may need reloading..  Did you follow all these steps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter

Comment: Yes i know these steps well, too well! It's as if MS really doesn't want you using the WinRT runtime! The problem happens even when i run the samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples) and [here](https://github.com/qmatteoq/DesktopBridge) along with my own app I'm trying to convert.

Comment: I haven't yet tried converting a WPF app to be hosted in MarketPlace... But I do know a bit about how it works,  they use VSIX packaging to get it into markeplace.  The error message you indicate above is too little to determine additonal information without digging out WINDBG and attaching it prior to a debug session to at least see what's going on.  The only problem then is that you won't have the PDB files so it's like debugging machine code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the WPF project in VS2017, I'd recommend to package directly from VS without using the DAC. see the article for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, i manually created my AppxManifest file in the debugging project. However, i still get the 'The parameter is incorrect error' anytime i run the project. I also get it anytime i try to run any of the Desktop Bridge Debugging Project samples from Github [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples). I guess it's a bit of a concern when Microsoft wants us to port applications to WinRT and they don't work, and there isn't really any information or explanation for why not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be related to the May Security Update. I restored Windows to the factory defaults and everything works fine.

However, once I install the the [May Security Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016871/windows-10-update-kb4016871) to address this bug with [Sql Server and Filestreams](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/filestream-issues-with-sql-server-on-windows-10-creators-update/), the Desktop Bridge Debugging project stops working.

I'm going to throw out a random guess that it's related to the Microsoft Malicious Software Removal Tool, as the event viewer logs mentioned an issue with the 'parameter is incorrect' referring to the Microsoft.MRT.

Of course it could be anything, and as only 7500 people have even downloaded the Desktop Bridge Debugging project in the first place, I doubt it's high on the list of Microsoft Developer Priorities.

And to be completely honest, it's really probably my fault for not rewriting the app as a UWP app, after rewriting it as a Windows Forms app, and as a Silverlight app, and as a WPF app and on and on and on. Although, I'm not sure how many glasses of Kool Aid are left in the punch bowl for me.